# jQuery setting Width using variable

Tags: jquery

```
var _headerwidth = $('#header').width();
var _foabgwidth = $('#page-body-inner').width();

console.log(_headerwidth);
console.log(_foabgwidth);
$('.static').css("width",_foabgwidth + "px");
$('.fixed').css("width",_headerwidth + "px");
var staticwidth = $('.static').width();
console.log('staticwidth:'+staticwidth);
```

Using the above code, my console logs are as follows

```
940
676
staticwidth:null
```

I'm trying to set the width for `.static` and `fixed` and I'm unable to get it to work using the jQuery I've used.

Comment: [No repro](http://jsfiddle.net/LSxUH/). Are you sure that an element with the class `static` exists in the DOM at the point of execution?

Comment: What does `$('.static').css('width')` give you?

Comment: Wath kind of elements are the ones with classes .static and .fixed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with this syntax:

```
$('.static').css({ width : _foabgwidth + "px" });
```

or this:

```
$('.static').css({ width : _foabgwidth });
```

Comment: That will get you the same.